# Вычисление процента от цены js

Tags: javascript, html, проценты

Пытаюсь сделать скрипт, который будет брать на сайте цену товара, вычислять от нее 1% и вписывать в другое поле. Важно что бы это происходило в реальном времени, без нажатия на кнопки, так как цена товара динамически может изменяться в зависимости от выбранного количества товара.

Условно html такого вида:

```html
<div id="product-price">100$</div>

<div>
<span>Ваш кешбэк:</span>
<strong id="bonus-price-result"><!--тут результат вычисления скрипта, в данном случае: 1$--></strong>
<span>$</span>
</div>
```

Сделал такого плана, но как получить данные цены товара из html и вернуть вычесления в поле кешбэка, не знаю :(

```js
prc=Math.round(100/100*1); {  
document.writeln ('Ваш кешбэк:' +prc+ '$');  
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь, надеюсь что это пригодится многим!

Answer (score 1):

JS  код по вашему условию.

```js
const product = document.getElementById('product-price');    
const result = document.getElementById('bonus-price-result');   

let price = +product.textContent / 100 * 1;
result.textContent = price;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Работает! Но к сожалению только статически, если изменить цену, то она пересчитается только при обновлении страницы.

Comment: Так это бред.  Что значит статически? Почему после обновления страничке?  Какая цена написана в product-price, такой % кеша и будет. Вы по другому не напишите. Хотите, что бы рандомно менялась цена, напишите тогда функцию  random. Все зависит от задачи. Динамика-  это изменение чего-то в зависимости от чего-то и сейчас  от цены нужный кеш бек. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Пример довольно прост. Чтобы ожидать изменений в дереве DOM, нужен [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Вводить цену в примере придется вручную.

При вводе будем устанавливать цену в слушающийся элемент цены.

Как только цена в слушающемся элементе поменялась - запускаем расчет процента. И, собственно, выводим процент...

```js
// Обсервер будет следить за изменением объекта и вызывать callback при изменении
// В callback производим все расчеты
let observer = new MutationObserver(() => perc.value=(priceLabel.innerHTML/100).toFixed(2));
// А изменения какого именно объекта - определяем первым аргументом ниже
// Вторым аргументом - конфиг
observer.observe(priceLabel,{attributes: true,childList: true, subtree: true});

// При отправке формы на сервер, выключим обсервер, заморозив процент 
document.forms[0].onsubmit = () => observer.disconnect()

// У нас нет источника цен, поэтому цены будем менять вручную
requestAnimationFrame(()=>(document.forms[0].oninput = ()=> priceLabel.innerHTML = price.value)());
```

```html
<form>
<!-- Этот тег для изменения цены: -->
Цена: <input id="price" type="number" value="68556764.5" /><br/>
<!-- а отсюда будет парситься цена: -->
Цена для получения: <div id="priceLabel"></div><br/>
<!-- А здесь выводить процент -->
Процент: <output id="perc"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! А как поступить если цена находится в обычном div на странице? Нужно как-то ее оттуда взять. Это больше для информации посетителя будет, отправлять на сервер не планируется.

Comment: Так цена берется из обычного `<output>`. Можно `<output>` заменить на `<div>` и ничего не изменится... Одно и тоже считай.

Comment: @AlexRuban. Поменял этот `<output>` на `<div>` (откуда слушается и парсится цена)

Comment: То есть процент я заменяю **не** по вводу цены в форме `<input>`, а по изменению цены в `<div>`. А по вводу цены в `<input>` заменяю цену в `<div>` (но это чисто для примера, у вас цена будет меняться другими скриптами)